# How can I use hypothesis, and pytest-tornado yield-based testing, in the same test case?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado, pytest, python-hypothesis

I'm writing [py.test](http://pytest.org/) tests of my code that uses the [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) library. How can I use [Hypothesis](http://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/) in my tests that involve coroutines and the IOLoop? I've been able to write yield-based tests without Hypothesis by using [pytest-tornado](https://github.com/eugeniy/pytest-tornado)'s `@pytest.mark.gen_test`, but when I try to combine it with `@given`, I receive the following error:

> FailedHealthCheck: Tests run under `@given` should return `None`, but `test_both` returned `<generator object test_both at 0x7fc4464525f0>` instead.
>
> See http://hypothesis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/healthchecks.html for more information about this. If you want to disable just this health check, add `HealthCheck.return_value` to the `suppress_health_check` settings for this test.

I'm pretty confident that this is a real problem and not just a question of disabling the health check, considering that the [Hypothesis docs](http://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/supported.html#testing-frameworks) say

> yield based tests simply won’t work.

Here's code that demonstrates my situation:

```
class MyHandler(RequestHandler):

    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self, x):
        yield gen.moment
        self.write(str(int(x) + 1))
        self.finish()


@pytest.fixture
def app():
    return Application([(r'/([0-9]+)', MyHandler)])


@given(x=strategies.integers(min_value=0))
def test_hypothesis(x):
    assert int(str(x)) == x


@pytest.mark.gen_test
def test_tornado(app, http_client, base_url):
    x = 123
    response = yield http_client.fetch('%s/%i' % (base_url, x))
    assert int(response.body) == x + 1


@pytest.mark.gen_test
@given(x=strategies.integers(min_value=0))
def test_both(x, app, http_client, base_url):
    response = yield http_client.fetch('%s/%i' % (base_url, x))
    assert int(response.body) == x + 1
```

`test_hypothesis` and `test_tornado` work fine, but I get the error with `test_both` because I'm using `yield` and Hypothesis together.

Changing the order of the decorators didn't change anything, probably because the `gen_test` decorator is simply an attribute mark.

Can I write tests of my Tornado-based code that use Hypothesis? How?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can accomplish this by calling [`run_sync()`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.run_sync) on the `io_loop` py.test fixture of pytest-tornado. This can be used in place of `yield`:

```
@given(x=strategies.integers(min_value=0))
def test_solution(x, app, http_client, base_url, io_loop):
    response = io_loop.run_sync(
        lambda: http_client.fetch('%s/%i' % (base_url, x)))
    assert int(response.body) == x + 1
```

Or you can place the body of your test in a coroutine, so that it can continue to use `yield`, and call this coroutine with `run_sync()`:

```
@given(x=strategies.integers(min_value=0))
def test_solution_general(x, app, http_client, base_url, io_loop):
    @gen.coroutine
    def test_gen():
        response = yield http_client.fetch('%s/%i' % (base_url, x))
        assert int(response.body) == x + 1
    io_loop.run_sync(test_gen)
```